# Every partition of a number using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

While doing some backtracking exercises, got stuck here:

> Write a recursive algorithm that generates all partitions of a given n
> numbers. Of the partitions that differ only in the order of the
> members, we need to list only one, the last from a lexicographic point
> of view. Write the solutions lexicographically in ascending order.
> 1 <= n <= 100

n = 5 would be:

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
2 2 1
3 1 1
3 2
4 1
5
```

I searched over the web for solutions and found [this](https://www.educative.io/m/find-all-sum-combinations), but it's not quite right and I don't know how to perfect it. First of all it's not in lexicographical order, and doesn't include the actual number.

So for 5 it outputs:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 
1 1 3
1 2 2
1 4 
2 3
```

Here is my code, where I tried to correct it, it's better, but still not exactly the way the example is..

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print(const vector<vector<int>>& output)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < output.size(); ++i){
    for(int j = output[i].size()-1; j >= 0; --j){
      cout << output[i][j] << " "; 
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void iteration(int n, int current_sum, int start, vector<vector<int>>& output, vector<int>& result)
{
    if (n == current_sum) {
        output.push_back(result);
    }

    for (int i = start; i < n; i++) {
        int temp = current_sum + i;
        if (temp <= n) {
            result.push_back(i);
            iteration(n, temp, i, output, result);
            result.pop_back();
        }
        else {
            return ;
        }
    }
}

void decompose(int n) 
{
    vector<vector<int>> output;
    vector<int> result;

    iteration(n, 0, 1, output, result);

    print(output);
    cout << n << endl;

    return ;
}

int main() 
{
    int n = 5;
    decompose(n);

    return 0;
}
```

So, now the output is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
2 1 1 1   
3 1 1
2 2 1
4 1
3 2
5
```

So, the 2 2 1 and 3 2 is in the wrong place.. And the bigger the "n" number is, the bigger the mess..

Can someone help?

Comment: Compile a debug version of the program and step slowly, taking good notes, through the program with whatever debugger came with your development tools. Watch everything the program does.  This is one of the best ways to understand the behaviour of code. Once you understand what it does and why it does it, you stand a chance at modifying the code to do what you want it to do. If you don't understand the behaviour   , any success you have will be from luck, and luck does not scale or port well.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get more practice programming, you'll learn how to keep things simple:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void decompose(int n, std::vector<int> prefix = {}) {
  if (n == 0) {
    for (int a : prefix) { std::cout << a << ' '; }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    int max = prefix.size() ? std::min(prefix.back(), n) : n;
    prefix.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
      prefix.back() = i;
      decompose(n - i, prefix);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  decompose(5);
}
```

Comment: This does indeed output the correct result! Thank you! Will spend further time on actually understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the answer ... here is some code that I translated from Python to C# a few years ago and just translated to C++ for this answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> join(int val, const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    std::vector<int> joined;
    joined.reserve(vec.size() + 1);
    joined.push_back(val);
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(joined));
    return joined;
}

std::vector<int> tail(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::vector<int> t(v.size() - 1);
    std::copy(std::next(v.begin()), v.end(), t.begin());
    return t;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> partitions(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return { {} };
    }
    auto partitions_n_minus_1 = partitions(n - 1);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> partitions_n;

    for (const auto& p: partitions_n_minus_1) {
        partitions_n.push_back( join({ 1 }, p) );
        if (!p.empty() && (p.size() < 2 || p[1] > p[0])) {
            partitions_n.push_back(join({ p[0] + 1 }, tail(p)));
        }
    }
    return partitions_n;
}

int main()
{
    auto partions = partitions( 6 );
    for (const auto& p : partions) {
        for (int i : p) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Python code this comes from is here, [Generator for integer partitions (Python recipe)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/218332-generator-for-integer-partitions/), with some explanation by the author in comments.

In my C# code I was able to retain the generator/yield idiom used in the Python version but I'm afraid I currently do not know how to use C++ coroutines yet so I've moved it to a standard function implementation which will be less efficient as it requires a lot of copying.